# cannot bind functions in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have tried all the possible solutions that I know of. I have tried several other solutions to similar problems but I do not understand how this is supposed to work. I am trying to call a function from inside a ListView renderRow method. I can now call the function but I cannot pass in the selected rowData that I need. This is what I am getting:

[image: screenshot]

I need the selected rowData. here is code

```
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmitTrip = this.onSubmitTrip.bind(this);
        this.onSelectTrip = this.onSelectTrip.bind(this);
        this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds,
            showSubmitTripBtn: false
        }
    }
    onSelectTrip(rowData) {
        selectedTrip = rowData;
    }

  renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onSelectTrip}  underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <View style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 24 }}>{rowData.tripName}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
```

Comment: *"I can now call the function but I cannot pass in the selected rowData that I need."* I don't see where you are calling the method. Passing the data is as simple as `this.renderRow(theData)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay from what I can see you aren't actually passing `onSelectTrip` your rowData when your TouchableHighlight is pressed.

```
// Change this
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this.onSelectTrip}
  underlayColor='#dddddd'
>

// To this
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => this.onSelectTrip(rowData)}
  underlayColor='#dddddd'
>
```

Also while looking at your screenshot I noticed another potential issue further down in the `onSelectTrip` method with your lodash `_.each` call. You need to pass `_.each` a fat arrow as the callback if you want to use `this.setState()` inside of it.

```
// Change this
_.each(rowData.routeLocations, function(item) {

// To this
_.each(rowData.routeLocations, (item) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the ES6 lambda's instead of explicitly binding all the methods in the class constructor to provide the lexical binding. I think this should solve your issue:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmitTrip = this.onSubmitTrip.bind(this);
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds,
        showSubmitTripBtn: false
    }
}

onSelectTrip = (rowData) => {
    selectedTrip = rowData;
}

renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onSelectTrip(rowData)}  underlayColor='#dddddd'>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <View style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 24 }}>{rowData.tripName}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

Comment: it appears it is trigging the function on page load. other than bunch of redlines underneath my code I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined(…) !!!

Comment: Is the above code complete? I am not seeing any `setState`

Comment: no, i will create plunker with all of it. wasnt sure what all you needed.

Comment: Try changing the anonymous function for `_.each` in `onSelectTrip` method with a lambda.

Comment: it allowed the view to load without issue. but the function is not being triggered onPress

Comment: I'm not sure of the big picture here, but at least here's one error in above code: `onPress` part should be `onPress={() => this.onSelectTrip(rowData)}` instead.